# Не работает вставка данных в таблицу SQLite

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Необходимо вписать данные в таблицу. При выполнении кода:

```
 id_v = cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM nat WHERE city = ? AND sex = ? ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1""",(city1, sex__)).fetchone()
    curs.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS liked(id_like text, id_liked text)""")
    id = m.message.chat.id
    curs.execute("""INSERT INTO liked VALUES (?,?)""", (id, id_v,))
```

выдает ошибку:

```
    curs.execute("""INSERT INTO liked VALUES (?,?)""", (id, id_v,))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id_v у вас является кортежом, что не поддерживается sqlite3, замените

```python
curs.execute("""INSERT INTO liked VALUES (?,?)""", (id, id_v,))
```

на

```python
curs.execute("""INSERT INTO liked VALUES (?,?)""", ((id,) + id_v) )
```

либо

```python
curs.execute("""INSERT INTO liked VALUES (?,?)""", (id, id_v[0],))
```